# How can you only make part of you Quill JS text editor read only?

Tags: quill

I am going through the QuillJS API on: https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/. I only see the ability to change the entire editor to read-only, but I was wondering whether there was a way to specify a section of the editor to be read only.

Comment: You can use custom blots to define whatever behavior you want, even non-editable experiences, but this would not be a quick config change.

Comment: Embed blots are read-only by design. Depending on your usage case, which you should include in order to make it easier for us, you could define one custom embed and replace the selected part with it, cloning the contents. Undoing this would be a little harder.